# Limit replay buffer by observable

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I have a stream with live data, and a stream which basically delimits parts of the live data that belong together. Now when someone subscribes to the live data stream, I would like to replay them the live data. However I don't want to remember all the live data, only the part since the last time the other stream emitted a value.

[There is an issue](https://rx.codeplex.com/workitem/44) which would solve my problem, since there is a replay operator which does exactly what I want (or at least I think).

What is currently the way to do this easily? Is there a better way than something like the following?

```
private class ReplayWithLimitObservable<TItem, TDelimiter> : IConnectableObservable<TItem>
{
    private readonly List<TItem> cached = new List<TItem>();
    private readonly IObservable<TDelimiter> delimitersObservable;
    private readonly IObservable<TItem> itemsObservable;
    public ReplayWithLimitObservable(IObservable<TItem> itemsObservable, IObservable<TDelimiter> delimitersObservable)
    {
        this.itemsObservable = itemsObservable;
        this.delimitersObservable = delimitersObservable;
    }

    public IDisposable Subscribe(IObserver<TItem> observer)
    {
        lock (cached)
        {
            cached.ForEach(observer.OnNext);
        }

        return itemsObservable.Subscribe(observer);
    }

    public IDisposable Connect()
    {
        var delimiters = delimitersObservable.Subscribe(
            p =>
                {
                    lock (cached)
                    {
                        cached.Clear();
                    }
                });
        var items = itemsObservable.Subscribe(
            p =>
                {
                    lock (cached)
                    {
                        cached.Add(p);
                    }
                });
        return Disposable.Create(
            () =>
                {
                    items.Dispose();
                    delimiters.Dispose();
                    lock (cached)
                    {
                        cached.Clear();
                    }
            });
}

public static IConnectableObservable<TItem> ReplayWithLimit<TItem, TDelimiter>(IObservable<TItem> items, IObservable<TDelimiter> delimiters)
{
    return new ReplayWithLimitObservable<TItem, TDelimiter>(items, delimiters);
}
```

Comment: Just a thought... wouldn't `ConcurrentBag<T>` be a better option than using `lock` on `cached`? I mean, that's what it's designed for...

Comment: @toadflakz - AFAIK, ConcurrentBag does not guarantee preserving order of addition (if the items observable behaves correctly, I get the items in correct order using a List). ConcurrentQueue could solve that, but clearing a list is easier than clearing a ConcurrentQueue.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation - I'm interested in realtime data development so code design decision insights from people with experience is appreciated.

Comment: I agree that your question represents a core limitation in the Framework and my work item that you mentioned which proposes to add "reactive/reactive" overloads to `Replay` could solve your problem.

Comment: Until then, your solution is fine except for a couple of problems:
1) Never implement `IObservable<T>` yourself. In this case, you need an `IConnectableObservable<T>` and it's quicker than implementing a custom subject; however, you should still derive from `ObservableBase<T>` to ensure auto-detach behavior, trampoline exists, etc.
2) Your `Subscribe` implementation has a race condition that could allow you to miss notifications. Make sure that you call `itemsObservable.Subscribe` within the lock.

Comment: Brandon's answer made me realize that my first point doesn't actually apply here because technically you're not implementing `IObservable<T>` yourself, you're still relying on an observable passed in as a parameter, thus you don't have to derive from `ObservableBase<T>`. My second point about the race condition bug still applies though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does this do what you want?  It has the advantage of leaving all of the locking and race conditions to the Rx pros :)

```
private class ReplayWithLimitObservable<T, TDelimiter> : IConnectableObservable<T>
{
  private IConnectableObservable<IObservable<T>> _source;

  public ReplayWithLimitObservable(IObservable<T> source, IObservable<TDelimiter> delimiter)
  {
    _source = source
      .Window(delimiter) // new replay window on delimiter
      .Select<IObservable<T>,IObservable<T>>(window =>
      {
        var replayWindow = window.Replay();

        // immediately connect and start memorizing values
        replayWindow.Connect();

        return replayWindow;
      })
      .Replay(1); // remember the latest window
  }

  IDisposable Connect()
  {
    return _source.Connect();
  }

  IDisposable Subscribe(IObserver<T> observer)
  {
    return _source
      .Concat()
      .Subscribe(observer);
  }
}

public static IConnectableObservable<TItem> ReplayWithLimit<TItem, TDelimiter>(IObservable<TItem> items, IObservable<TDelimiter> delimiters)
{
    return new ReplayWithLimitObservable<TItem, TDelimiter>(items, delimiters);
}
```

Comment: This is better, but I still don't like the fact that `IConnectableObservable<T>` has to be implemented. That should never be true, don't you think? You're so close to avoiding it here, yet still so far... ;-)

Comment: At the very least, [this](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/Rx.NET/issues/54), though a "reactive/reactive" version of `ReplaySubject<T>` would be best. It would solve this problem in a line of code: `return xs.Multicast(new ReplaySubject<T>(ys));`

Comment: @DaveSexton - Totally agree, my reaction to this question was that a factory for `IConnectableObservable<T>` would indeed be a welcome addition to Rx.

Comment: Nice answer Brandon, particularly the mechanic with the `Replay(1)` and deferred `Concat` - very nice.

Comment: Yeah I tried to do it with window and replay, but the `Replay(1)` didn't occur to me. Thanks, this is what I was looking for.